# nautilus not call write system call when paste file

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, nautilus, system-calls

I'm trying to hook some system calls using linux kernel module on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop version.

However, when I hooked `write(unsigned int fd, const char __user *buf, size_t count)` and turned `fd` into filename, I found that when I copy `/home/user/1.txt` and paste to `/home/user/folder/` in nautilus, no write was called in this folder. However, if I use `cp /home/user/1.txt /home/user/folder`, I can notice `write` is called and the filename is exactly `/home/user/folder/1.txt`.

I've tried hook `pwrite` also but still no detection of calling it when paste file using nautilus.

So, how does nautilus copy file and paste to specific folder when no `write` system call is called on destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Nautilus uses different approach for optimization purposes.

Say I have a test file `/ntest/testfile` with 45 bytes inside:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Leroooy Jeeenkins
```

I want to move it into directory `/ntest2`. To trace what exactly Nautilus does, I can launch it like this (actually, I did multiple launches with less strict limitations, but this is a good start):

```
strace -f -P '/ntest/testfile' -P '/ntest2/testfile' -qq nautilus
```

Essentially, the following excerpt explains what happens (note that `pipe2()` call is not captured by the command above - I inserted it based on other tracing sessions):

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/ntest/testfile", O_RDONLY) = 35
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/ntest2/testfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644) = 36
pipe2([37, 38], O_CLOEXEC)  = 0
stat("/ntest2/testfile", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
splice(35, [0], 38, NULL, 1048576, SPLICE_F_MORE) = 45
splice(37, NULL, 36, [0], 45, SPLICE_F_MORE) = 45
close(35)                   = 0
close(36)                   = 0
```

Nautilus uses `splice(2)` which allows transferring some data between `fd`s without copying it between kernel and user spaces. Because `man 2 splice` requires one of ends to be a pipe, Nautilus creates a pipe with input file descriptor `38` and output file descriptor `37`. After opening source and destination files and creating the pipe, Nautilus uses `splice()` to read data from source file to the pipe's input; then the second `splice()` is used to write data from this pipe to the output file. This approach does not involve kernel-to-user and user-to-kernel data transitions as it would be with ordinary `read()`-`write()` approach.

Note, that this behavior is not specific to Nautilus, but rather to the library it uses (glib). It looks like [this is the splice() call](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/71bbe9f3e09c9ef9caac122f298fd11b755a40df/gio/gfile.c#L2974) we observe, as Nautilus uses glib's [g_file_copy()](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus/blob/af87a20dc56f1b1ad4a87534bac5c1ff71ddda71/src/nautilus-file-operations.c#L5224) which, in turn, calls [file_copy_fallback()](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/71bbe9f3e09c9ef9caac122f298fd11b755a40df/gio/gfile.c#L3528) -> [splice_stream_with_progress()](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/71bbe9f3e09c9ef9caac122f298fd11b755a40df/gio/gfile.c#L3343) -> [do_splice()](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/71bbe9f3e09c9ef9caac122f298fd11b755a40df/gio/gfile.c#L3085).

Comment: Thanks man! Is there a way to get the data from splice?

Comment: Splice is not an object, it is an operation, so you can't get data from it. At the beginning of first `splice()` call the data is not even read from original file, and at the end of the second `splice()` call the data is already written to the destination file.